# Temp and state change of water in a perfect void

Tags: thermodynamics, water, vacuum, states-of-matter

**Let's say that I was able to instantaneously  transport spherical volume of water into a perfect vacuum, with no external gravity present, and no light or heat sources present - a void**

Would the volume stay perfectly at a particular temperature because there are no other molecules for the thermal energy to disperse within?

Will it boil? My initial inclination here is that the water will boil due to lack of pressure. However, I think that this requires some heat/energy source for the state change to happen? Is there inherent energy in the water molecules that allows it to change state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does depend on the size of the sphere. If it is planet-sized gravity will hold it together. Since some of the molecules will travel fast enough to escape, the temperature will drop as they do, until the residue is ice.

In a small sphere the molecules will have a range of speeds. Many of them will be traveling fast enough that the forces between them will not hold them together, so much of the water will become a gas. Others will be slower (especially after being slowed by the forces attractng them to other molecules) and will attract each other and come together; they would eventually form a body of ice. The proportions of ice and gas will depend on the temperature of the original water.

Boiling is when bubbles of vapour form inside the liquid; they would only occur if part of the liquid was hotter and expanding faster than neighbouring regions. Small bubbles might form for a short time.

Comment: I have qualms about your answer. 1) In a perfect void, wouldn't a sphere of any liquid with surface tension stay a perfect sphere regardless of size? 2) What do you mean by "traveling fast enough?" - why is anything moving? 3) Assuming a uniform temp to begin with, why/how is anything changing temperature if there is no difference in temperature anywhere, save for outside of the sphere where the void is? How would the molecules cool (or warm) if they are in contact with themselves and nothing else?

Comment: Hrmm... Oh, I think I might understand what you mean about the size. Possibly. I suppose that it would expand with no pressure, but would it change state or temperature, and why?

Comment: @Tim, liquid water cannot exist in very low pressure, so it must change to gas and/or solid. How much of each depends on how much energy there was in the original water.

Comment: fair ... but ... is it able to change state to a gas without a heat source?

Comment: @Tim, it already contains heat. This is why some of the water in a cup of hot water will evaporate without any additional heat source, taking some of the heat with it and cooling the rest of the water.